# Using Bootstrap for its scaffolding grid only - without any of the front end html elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Im developing a custom html / css / js front end from scratch, ie. all the elements are designed and i dont need a front end framework with buttons, headers, layouts etc.

What i do need however is a responsive scaffolding grid (i know i could write this from scratch but why reinvent the wheel) Id like to use bootstraps scaffolding grid system as im familiar with it from other projects ive worked on (where i was using the frameworks design elements).

Is there a simple way to do this, without overriding the css of every element in my `custom-styles.css` file ?

Answer (score 1):

Download the LESS or SASS source, and compile only the areas you want to include in your project.

Comment: thanks, but dont normally use LESS or SASS is there anyway to do this with the normal distribution of bootstrap ?

Comment: You could manually delete everything but the border-box reset and the container, row, and col-\* rules, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Made this Grunt build with only the Bootstrap 3.3.5 grid:

https://github.com/horgen/grunt-builds/tree/master/bootstrap-grid

~10KB minimized.

If you need some other parts from Bootstrap just include them in /src/less/bootstrap.less.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the customize option here
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Select just scafolding and responsive utilities.
You might have to change some more stuff because the normalizing css is still included